# Issue with Page Category Changing After Adding Product Catalog

Tags: facebook, adsmanager

In Meta Business Manager, we're managing a product catalog for a client who has never added a product catalog to their business management; the pages underneath the account are transformed to be classified as "Online Sellers."

Could this category change to "Online Sellers" directly result from adding the product feed to the Commerce Manager?

Any insights or similar experiences would be greatly appreciated, as we're trying to understand the implications of this transition and how to manage it moving forward.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.